# Registration id in pushnotification is of mobile or email id

Tags: android, push-notification

I m trying to make an application using push notification.
I m  making different gmail account but i m getting same registration id to send on Php server
m confused that the registration id is of mobile or gmail account ??

Answer (score 1):

It uses device id.Every time a new device gets registered,GCM returns registration Id which can be used to for push notification to corresponding device

For you reference:
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/